# delay measured by tcpdump timestamp increases without a reason

Tags: timestamp, tcpdump

I am measuring the delay or latency faced by packets inside a gateway by caputuring the packets using tcpdump in the entry and exit NICs of the gateway.
I am sending about 800,000 packets from a source host to a destination host which are connected through two GWs(i.e. Source Host=>GW1=>GW2=>Destination Host).
I measured the latency on each GW by subtracting the timestamps at the entry NIC from that on the exit NIC.
I found that the latency is continuously increasing from 2 to 3000 microsecond. 
When I interchanged the NICs, the latency is increasing for some time and sharply decreasing and increasing again.

And suprisingly even though the latency on GW increases, the end-to-end throughput remains the same of about 900Mbps when all nodes have 1000Mbps NIC.

Would you please let me know how such variation in the latency happened?
Or how the tcpdump timestamp was delayed in the exit NIC?
Is there any approach to have the timestamp in nanosecond granularity?

---

Thanks for responding.

The performance of the infrastructure is not a problem. Here we are measuring the performance by throughput and found that the throughput does not decrease even if the latency on GW increases from 2 micro second to 3000 micro second.

For additional information: I have been measuring the latency on GW when the GW is doing different roles, such as an IP router, a GRE tunneling point, or a NAT. When it works as an IP router, the delay experienced by packets inside the GW is almost <=4 microsecond. However when the GW functions as a GRE tunneling point, the delays continuously increase by 1000 times within a few seconds. This is the problem in my measurement. And since there is not change in end-to-end throughput, I guess this delays is not a real one, it might have been introduced by the packet capturing and timestamping functions of tcpdump.

Answer (score 1):

I could be thinking too obvious here but I'm thinking that what you're referring to is [jitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter) and simple [packet delay variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_delay_variation) that is a fact of every day life.

These days, to save CPU cycles, there's [TCP offload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine) on NICs and performance varies across NICs, which could account for the differences when you switch.

Given the tiny time differences that you mention, is it causing a problem on the performance of your infrastructure?

You should also monitor the performance of the two gateways to see if the latency changes correspond to load increases on the gateways.